# First fetch call returns empty array call but works on the second and so on?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

As mentioned above, whenever I fetch data to set the value to a state, it only sets the state at the second time i input the amount charged, currency and fysigned fields. My main question is why does it fetch an empty array the first time i input values in those fields? **The first time the value is undefined**
[image]
[image]

**CODE**

```
setUSDValue() {
const { AmountCharged, Currency, FYSigned} = this.state;

if(AmountCharged && Currency && FYSigned)
{
  fetch(`http://ca-fpscfb2:2000/USDValueExchangeRateValue?rateYear=${FYSigned}&USD=${Currency}&CAD=${Currency}&INR=${Currency}&GBP=${Currency}`)
  .then(response => response.json().then(response =>  
    this.setState(
    { 
      exchangeRateVal: response.data 

    }

    )))
  .then( 
    this.state.exchangeRateVal && this.state.exchangeRateVal.map((rate) =>
    (
      this.setState({
        USDValue: rate.USD
      })
    ))  
  )
}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that state doesn't update immediately when calling `this.setState`. Try using a callback function if you need that code run directly after state is updated:

```
setUSDValue() {
const { AmountCharged, Currency, FYSigned} = this.state;

if(AmountCharged && Currency && FYSigned)
{
  fetch(`http://ca-fpscfb2:2000/USDValueExchangeRateValue?rateYear=${FYSigned}&USD=${Currency}&CAD=${Currency}&INR=${Currency}&GBP=${Currency}`)
  .then(response => response.json().then(response =>  
    this.setState(
    { 
      exchangeRateVal: response.data 

    },
    () =>
    this.state.exchangeRateVal.map((rate) =>
    (
      this.setState({
        USDValue: rate.USD
      })
    ))  

    )))
}
```

Comment: I get an error when trying a call back, i get this **Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received:** On the line where **Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received:**

Comment: @bobb1213131 I updated my response it should work now